# Old PC lags on the desktop. (Keyboard and mouse lag)

Tags: hard-drive, memory, keyboard, mouse

I have an old AM3+ pc I built a couple years back which was fine until today. I put new [RAM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BMLTB9P9) in the pc a couple days ago and it worked. Today I put my used WD Black 3.5" in (formatted it); then began to install WoW. the mouse began to lag and my keyboard would spam letters when I would type them. Is it my RAM? I haven't checked to see if the installation of windows needs updating. What drivers would need to be checked for updates for something like this? It's not usable as it is. Any help is appreciated. (Running Windows 10 x64)

Comment: Perhaps update all your drivers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you replace back in the old RAM does the issue go away? Maybe the new RAM is being under clocked and you can check that in the BIOs to see if it's being read right.

Comment: are mouse and keyboard wired or wireless? Seen that sort of thing happen on wireless mouse/keyboard

Comment: wireless but I've not experienced that before with these. plus it doesn't seem like they should both go out at the same time.

Comment: Also I haven't had a chance to put the ram back in yet. I'll do that as soon as I can; but until at least tomorrow I can't.

Comment: @John Windows Device drivers?

Comment: I would suggest all drivers to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @John excuse me for having to ask; are there other drivers you would suggest? I don't want to miss important steps.

Comment: Power Drivers, Video Driver, Firmware, Mouse

Comment: The word "spam" is imprecise in this context. Please use the EDIT button and make your question more clear, including by adding all information others have requested or that you've added in comments. Is the keyboard entering multiple of each key that you press, or keys that you haven't pressed?